# Communication between webservice and android

Tags: php, android, web-services, drupal-7

I'm new in android, I want to send My Drupal 7 content to Android. I can just send a $Variuable to android in this PHP webservice. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module for doing this. Also you need to install rest server

After this module is installed you can create your own endpoint in admin->structure->serviecs

You can add new custom rest services via views using [services_views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) or in your custom module.

1. Create custom module then write the below code to manually create a REST service.

// services resources
function YOURMODULE_services_resources() {

```
$resources = array(
    'ups' => array(
        'actions' => array(
            'yourservice' => array(
                'help' => t('Service details.'),
                'callback' => 'your_rest_api_callback_function',
                'args' => array(),
                'access arguments' => array('access content'),
                'access arguments append' => false,
                'args' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'data',
                        'type' => 'array',
                        'description' => 'Arguments description.',
                        'source' => 'data',
                        'optional' => TRUE,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

return $resources;
```

}

```
function your_rest_api_callback_function($data) {
   // in $data you will get the passed arguments
   $returnarr = "this is the content you need to return"
    return $returnarr;
}
```

Then enable this services form your new api created in admin->structure->services

You can specify the return data format in this module configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In android you have to create a async task in order to communicate with the server. Than you can send and receive variables from php script. ( you need to encode your variables in json format in php service before you sent.) Check this link;
http://www.sitepoint.com/lets-talk-1/

Comment: I can do that. I need send a drupal content